# Splash screen not working in wpf using mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, subscriber

I am trying to display splash screen (i.e) I have separately created a splash view and viewmodel for that. I am managing its visibility using mvvm subscribers and publishers.

But the issue currently I am facing is that my Splash screen is not visible when any task started.

**Splash Screen View:**

```
<Grid>
        <!--Splash Screen -->
        <Border x:Name="Splashbrd"  Style="{StaticResource SettingOuterBorderStyle}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding EnableSplash,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <Border Style="{StaticResource ProgressBorderStyle}">
                <StackPanel  Margin="10"  >
                    <ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SplashText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"  FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="12"
                                        Margin="5,5,5,0" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

**SplashScreenViewModel**

```
private void SubscribeSplashScreenEvent()
        {
            SubscriptionToken _subscribeSplashEvent = this._eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<ISplashScreenEvent>>().Subscribe(i =>
            {
                Showprogress(i.SplashVisibilty);
                SplashText = i.SplashText;
            });
        }


        #region SplashScreen
        private Visibility _enablesplash = Visibility.Hidden;
        public Visibility EnableSplash
        {
            get { return _enablesplash; }
            set
            {
                if (_enablesplash != value)
                {
                    _enablesplash = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private string _splashtext;
        public string SplashText
        {
            get { return _splashtext; }
            set
            {
                _splashtext = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public void Showprogress(bool bvisible)
        {
            EnableSplash = bvisible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        #endregion
```

**ViewWhereIamUsing**:

```
private void PublishSplashScreenEvent(bool _splashVisibilty, string _splashText = null)
        {
            var eventObj = new SplashScreenEvent
            {
                SplashVisibilty = _splashVisibilty,
                SplashText = _splashText
            };
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<ISplashScreenEvent>>().Publish(eventObj);
        }
 BackgroundWorker impworker = new BackgroundWorker();
                impworker.DoWork += test;
                impworker.RunWorkerCompleted += OntestCompleted;

//void test()
{
 PublishSplashScreenEvent(true, "testimg spash......");
}
void OntestCompleted()
{
PublishSplashScreenEvent(false);
}
```

**HowIRegister**:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.SplashScreenView}"></ContentControl>

_innerRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.SplashScreenView, typeof(SplashScreenView));
```

Please let me know where I am wrong and why my splash screen is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked over the code and I think the problem may be on the RaisePropertyChanged call.

Try to provide the property name:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("EnableSplash")
```

Also, I think you do not need to force Mode=TwoWay in a Visibility property.

Comment: tried your changes too still not working..one question is it a good idea to use event publishing in background worker that i am doing currently..not sure

Comment: Did you ensure the view is linked with the correct DataContext? I cant see that part on the xaml. About your question; no problem but ensure that UI updates are made on the UI thread (change context if neeeded).